# Underdetermined IBVP's: constructing boundary condition during evolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

For $(t,x)\in[0,T]\times[0,X]$ let there be a partial differential equation (PDE) of the generic form
$$\partial_ty=f(t,x,y,\partial_xy)$$
along with some initial condition (i.c.)
$$y_i(x):=y(0,x)$$
but no boundary condition (b.c.).

The above initial-boundary value problem (IBVP) is profoundly underdetermined.

However one may come to think that for some infinitesimal $h$ there are two distinct approximations for the $x$-partial derivative:
$$\partial_xy\approx\frac{y(t,x+h)-f(t,x)}{h}\qquad\qquad\partial_xy\approx\frac{y(t,x)-f(t,x-h)}{h}$$

Based on these approximations one can

1. evaluate $\partial_xy(0,x)$ for  any $x\in[0,X]$ and then
2. evaluate $\partial_ty(0,x)$ for  any $x\in[0,X]$ and then
3. evaluate $y(0+dt,x)=y(0,x)+dt\cdot \partial_ty(0,x)$

In this way one is able to construct a unique solution $y(t,x)$ although the above IBVP  is underdetermined. It is as if the missing   boundary condition $y(t,X)$ is constructed in parallel with the evolution of initial data.

I would appreciate any recommendations of bibliography or ideas concerning this kind of integration.